# What is the Delphi equivalent to the C __builtin_clz()?

Tags: delphi

Quoted from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html,

> — Built-in Function: `int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)`
>       Returns the number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is undefined.

What is the Delphi equivalent to the C __builtin_clz() ? If there isn't, how to implement it efficiently in Delphi?

Actually, I want to use it to calculate the base-2 logarithm of an integer.

Comment: [Find first set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set).

Comment: Integer Log base 2: `function IntLog2 Value: integer ): integer;
        asm
           BSR EAX, EAX
        end;`. You have to check for zero, as David mentioned. See http://www.codexterity.com/intlog2.htm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only care about 32 bit code then it goes like this:

```
function __builtin_clz(x: Cardinal): Cardinal;
asm
  BSR     EAX,EAX
  NEG     EAX
  ADD     EAX,32
end;
```

Or if you want to support 64 bit code as well then it would be:

```
function __builtin_clz(x: Cardinal): Cardinal;
{$IF Defined(CPUX64)}
asm
  BSR     ECX,ECX
  NEG     ECX
  ADD     ECX,31
  MOV     EAX,ECX
{$ENDIF}
{$IF Defined(CPUX86)}
asm
  BSR     EAX,EAX
  NEG     EAX
  ADD     EAX,31
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

It's likely that an asm guru could trim this down a little, but `BSR` (bit scan reverse) is the key instruction.

For the mobile compilers, I don't know how to do this efficiently.

Comment: @David_Heffernan - It's so fast answer, thank's for providing 32-bit and 64-bit implementation of `__builtin_clz`. For other platforms, I will implement it using pure Pascal code based on fast portable algorithms for `__builtin_clz` that is scattered on the Internet.

Comment: FWIW, I suspect that the implementations here differ from GCC when x is 0. Of course, they state that it is undefined, but just so that you are aware. Of course, you know how to handle log of zero!

Comment: @Astaroth, for other processors see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Hardware_support